# Permanent Config File in Pylint

Tags: macos, configuration-files, pylint

I've setup a custom configuration file for Pylint (name, conveniently, config). There has to be a way that I don't have to include `--rcfile=config` on every run. How can I set the config file permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the path to that file in the PYLINTRC environment variable, or rename the file $HOME/.pylintrc or /etc/pylintrc (the latter is probably only supported on *nix)

Comment: Where is the environment variable located? I found a folder ~/.pylint.d but it only contains stats on past runs.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Environment variables are OS level things. What is your operating system ?

Comment: Running OS X Lion. So I would save it at ~/.pylintrc?

Comment: not a max user myself. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x will be helpful.

Comment: But yes, saving the file as ~/.pylintrc should definitely do the trick.

Comment: according to the man page the sytem wide config should be in /etc/pylintrc

Answer (score 6):

When you do not specify the --rcfile option, Pylint searches for a configuration file in the following order and uses the first one it finds:

1. `pylintrc` in the current working directory
2. If the current working directory is in a Python module, Pylint
   searches up the hierarchy of Python modules until it finds a
   `pylintrc` file. This allows you to specify coding standards on a
   module-by-module basis. Of course, a directory is judged to be a
   Python module if it contains an `__init__.py` file.
3. The file named by environment variable PYLINTRC
4. `.pylintrc` in your home directory, unless you have no home directory
   or your home directory is /root
5. `.pylintrc` in the current working directory
6. `/etc/pylintrc`

Thus depending on the method you choose, Pylint can use a different configuration file based on the location of the code, the user or the machine.

Note that the configuration file only applies to Python files that are in modules.  Thus, **Pylint still uses its default rules when analyzing Python files in a directory with no `__init__.py` file**.

For example, I have a `bin/` directory containing command line applications.  Ordinarily, this directory needs no `__init__.py` file because it is never imported.  I had to add a `bin/__init__.py` file to get Pylint to analyze these Python files using my `pylintrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `.pre-commit-config.yaml`. This snippet below need to be added to `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pylint
        name: pylint
        entry: pylint
        language: system
        types: [python]
        args: [
            "-rn", # Only display messages
            "-sn", # Don't display the score
            "--rcfile=.pylintrc", # Link to your config file
            "--load-plugins=pylint.extensions.docparams", # Load an extension
          ]
```