# Getting Eclipse to recognise a Pylint "pylint.rc" file

Tags: eclipse, pydev, pylint

I'm trying to get Eclipse to recognise the PyLint configuration file that I use in Jenkins. At the moment Eclipse pylint swamps me with useless errors. I've tried passing in the rcfile parameter. So...

Windows > preferences > PyDev > PyLint

Then in "arguments to pass to pylint" I have
--rcfile=absolute_path_to_pylint.rc

This has no effect.

I've read that pylint will work if you drop a config file in your home directory, or set an Environmental variable (See: [Permanent Config File in Pylint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665579/permanent-config-file-in-pylint)) but both these solutions are a little unwieldy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm encountering the same issue right now with Eclipse Indigo and PyDev 2.7.3

Comment: I found the reason for my issue - I had PEP8 enabled, which returned its own warnings and errors; that's why I had an impression of pylint not recognizing --rcfile flag. Disabled PEP8 and everything works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup should work IMO. Double check that you don't have a typo in the path and that there is no syntax error in the rcfile preventing pylint from loading it (this could be related to a different pylint version being used in pydev and jenkins for instance).

If this still does not work, I think you should take the discussion to the pydev mailing list.